# How to get view count for Facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use FB Graph API (PHP)

I submit a new post with:

$check = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$val);

I got the post ID with $check['id']

I can get the like count with: 
http://graph.facebook.com/THE_ID

But if i want to grab the VIEW count of this post ...

How I can dot this ?

THANKS !

Answer (score 3):

You can't. To the best of my knowledge, the FB Graph API doesn't publicly expose post view counts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get the number of views of a status update. They only offer view count data for apps and pages via the Insight API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#Metrics

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a bit old :) but I hope someome finds this answer as I found elsewhere (not here).

You can retrieve page posts data, using this syntax:

```
{post-id}/insights/post_impressions_viral?fields=id,name,values&period=day
```

I don't think Facebook can measure 'real views' of a specific page (since it is shown in users' feed and they can sweep up on his phone quickly not really 'seeing' it, for example). I think post impressions are anyway a good measure to analyze.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

according to fb insights api (v2.8)
you can get post impressions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/insights#availmetrics

the metric you want is "post_impressions" or "post_impressions_unique"

this is how you make the call

GET v2.8/{post_id}/insights/post_impressions HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com